# Installing Fake boxwood on concrete vinyl siding

Tags: concrete, siding, green, planting

We are trying to add boxwood on what I believe is concrete siding and I believe the only way to do so is by making a frame on the back wall that will have to be drilled into wall. Can I drill in the this siding and will that create any issues? Is there any other way to do this?

[image]

Comment: you are asking if drilling an unknown wall will create issues .... you need to be certain about the wall before the question can be answered

Comment: what is the picture supposed to show? ... is that the wall that you want to drill?

Comment: There's no such thing as concrete siding, in my experience--there's just concrete and not concrete. There are many cement-based siding products, but you need to be more specific.